# Describe the shape formed by solutions to a complex quartic equation

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, roots

Here is the question:

[image]

My answers:

i) a generic quadrilateral or a triangle (isosceles or equilateral???)

Since the real roots are distinct, we cannot have a line here, and we can form any quadrilateral depending on the position of the roots. If one of the real roots share the real part with the imaginery roots, an isoscles triangle is formed
(Also I am pretty sure, an equilateral triangle can somehow be formed, but I am not sure how to show it)

[image]
ii) Isoscles triangle or a line
If the real root is the same as the real part of the complex roots we have a line. Otherwise it's a isosscles triangle (Again I am sure it can be equilateral)
[image]

iii) trapezium or a line

The lines formed by the conjugate pairs are parallel, so a trapezium is formed. If the roots are repeated, we have a line
[image]

Is my reasoning correct here? Do I miss something? Thanks for help.

Comment: The quadrilateral in part 1 is not entirely generic, since it must have an axis of symmetry. This shape is called a [kite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kite_(geometry))

Comment: @eyeballfrog I see that now thanks for the help, but I think it only holds if the real roots are either side of the complex roots. What about the case where they are on one side?

Comment: That's still a kite, just a concave one.

Comment: Just found out what a dart is. Thanks again!